# Biginsights 3.0 silent installation using Chef

Tags: java, shell, hadoop, chef-infra, biginsights

I am doing silent installation of Biginsights 3.0 using Chef. Strange thing is that if I invoke the installation without Chef recipe i.e manually "./silent-install.sh  install.xml" it works fine. But when I invoke it through Chef recipe , it fails. It does not install bigsql1,sheets and due that it fails. I am pasting the error. It is not getting required files as bigsql1 installation is not completing successfully.

```
[ERROR] DeployManager - bigsql1 failed
com.ibm.xap.mgmt.ConfigurationException: initialize failed because /opt/ibm/biginsights/hdm/components/bigsql1/binary/bigsql1-dist.tar.gz is not found
    at com.ibm.xap.mgmt.bigsql.BigSQL1Deployer.installInitialize(BigSQL1Deployer.java:73)
    at com.ibm.xap.mgmt.DeployManager$InstallThread.doInstall(DeployManager.java:2760)
    at com.ibm.xap.mgmt.DeployManager$InstallThread.work(DeployManager.java:2818)
    at com.ibm.xap.mgmt.DeployManager$WorkerThread.run(DeployManager.java:2725)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am sure somewhere Chef is failing to invoke bigsql1 install script and most probably it is terminal issue.

Here is my recipe code

```
bash "BI3.0" do
user "biadmin"
group "biadmin"
cwd "/home/biadmin/biginsights-3.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-enterprise-production-Linux-amd64-b20140711_1047/silent-install"
code <<-EOH
sh silent-install.sh BI30.xml 2>&1 >> /tmp/console.out
EOH
end
```

Comment: Please include your recipe code as well.

Comment: Here is my recipe code, BI30.xml and install.xml mentioned above are same.

Comment: I would presume that the output didn't provide any clues. The common issues with scripts like this are either the PATH or locale environment variables not being what you expect due to Chef not running any interactive `rc` or `profile` files.

Comment: yes,  but any workaround or solution ?

Comment: Set the required env vars in your little shell script snippet in the recipe.

Comment: Like coderanger said, after your `code` block you can do something like `environment 'BIG_HOME' => "/opt/ibm/biginsights"` or whatever environment variable it's looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestion but that is where the problem is. After doing lot of debugging I am still not able to find where its failing and why its failing. Otherwise I would have done what you have suggested.